# fscanf_s() 関数でEOFを認識できない理由と対処方法が知りたい。

Tags: c++

提示コードのコメント部の内部のコードですがなぜfscanf_s()関数の戻り値が**EOF**なのになぜ**EOF**が返ってこないのでしょうか？**公式リファレンスを見ましたがおかしいです**。

マイクロソフト公式リファレンス: https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fscanf-s-fscanf-s-l-fwscanf-s-fwscanf-s-l?view=msvc-160

```
#include "../Header/Model.hpp"

//数学ライブラリ
#include "../Library/glm/ext.hpp"

//標準ヘッダー
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string>


//コンストラクタ
Model::Model(const char* file)
{
    FILE* fp = nullptr;
    fopen_s(&fp,file,"r");  //読み込み専用でファイルを開く

    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // #############################################################################
            printf("あああ\n");
            char lineHeader[128] = { 0 };
            int res = fscanf_s(fp,"%s",lineHeader);
            printf("%d\n",&res);
            if (res == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            // ##############################################################################
            else
            {   
                //ファイル抽出


                //頂点を抽出
                if (strcmp(lineHeader, "v") == 0)
                {
                    glm::vec3 vertex;
                    fscanf_s(fp, "%f %f %f", &vertex.x, &vertex.y, &vertex.z);
                    out_vertices.push_back(vertex);
                }

                //UV座標を抽出
                else if (strcmp(lineHeader, "vt") == 0)
                {
                    glm::vec2 uv = glm::vec2(0,0);
                    fscanf_s(fp,"%f %fn",uv.x,uv.y);
                    out_uvs.push_back(uv);
                }

                //法線を抽出
                else if (strcmp(lineHeader, "vn") == 0)
                {
                    glm::vec3 normalize = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0 );
                    fscanf_s(fp, "%f %f %fn",normalize.x, normalize.y, normalize.z);
                    out_normals.push_back(normalize);
                }

                //面法線
                else if (strcmp(lineHeader, "f") == 0)
                {
                    std::string vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;
                    unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3],normalIndex[3];

                    int matches = fscanf_s(fp, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%dn",
                        & vertexIndex[0], &vertexIndex[1], &vertexIndex[2],
                        &uvIndex[0], &uvIndex[1], &uvIndex[2],
                        &normalIndex[0], &normalIndex[1], &normalIndex[2]);

                        if (matches != 9)
                        {
                            printf("エラー\n");    
                        }

                    out_vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[0]);
                    vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
                    vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);
                    uvIndices.push_back(uvIndex[0]);
                    uvIndices.push_back(uvIndex[1]);
                    uvIndices.push_back(uvIndex[2]);
                    normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[0]);
                    normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[1]);
                    normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[2]);
                }
            }
        }


        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < out_vertexIndices.size(); i++)
        {
            unsigned int vertexIndex = vertexIndices[i];
            glm::vec3 vertex = out_vertices[vertexIndex - 1];
            out_vertices.push_back(vertex);
        }

        printf(".objファイル読み込み完了!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ファイルが読めませんでした。\n");
    }
}



//デストラクタ
Model::~Model()
{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> int res = fscanf_s(fp,"%s",lineHeader);
> ```

この部分ですが引数が誤っています。引用されたドキュメントにも

> より安全な関数 ( _s サフィックスを持つ) とその他のバージョンの主な違いは、セキュリティが強化された関数では、各 c、 c、 s、 s、および [ 型フィールドの文字数を、変数の直後の引数として渡す必要があることです。

と説明されているように通常の`fscanf`と異なりセキュリティ強化された`fscanf_s`では`lineHeader`のサイズ情報が必要です。正しくは

```
int res = fscanf_s(fp, "%s", lineHeader, _countof(lineHeader));
```

です。コンパイラも警告してくれるはずですが、無視しているのでしょうか？

警告メッセージ：

```
warning C4473: 'fscanf_s' : not enough arguments passed for format string
message : placeholders and their parameters expect 2 variadic arguments, but 1 were provided
message : the missing variadic argument 2 is required by format string '%s'
message : this argument is used as a buffer size
```

---

> ```
> printf("%d\n",&res);
> ```

このコードは変数`res`のアドレスを出力するだけで何の意味もありません。正しくは

```
printf("%d\n", res);
```

のはずです。ここもコンパイラが警告してくれるはずですが、無視しているのでしょうか？

警告メッセージ：

```
warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int *'
```

---

> ```
> fscanf_s(fp,"%f %fn",uv.x,uv.y);
> ```

これでは読み込めません。コンパイラも警告してくれるはずですが、無視しているのでしょうか？

警告メッセージ：

```
warning C4477: 'fscanf_s' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'float *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double'
warning C4477: 'fscanf_s' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'float *', but variadic argument 2 has type 'double'
```

---

他にも多数の問題を抱えていると思われます。**無理やり実行する前に、コンパイラの警告に真摯に向き合うことをお勧めします。**

補足：

`printf`系や`scanf`系などの可変引数関数の場合、コンパイラーは与えられた引数を忠実に受け渡しします。しかしそれは正常動作することを意味するわけではありません。（可変引数に限らず）関数仕様に則り、正しい引数を与えるのはプログラマの責務です。

Comment: 落ち着いて思考することを学びました。ありがとうざいます。